# How to specify colors of stack categories in stacked column chart of amCharts?

Tags: amcharts

I am using a stacked column chart from amCharts. It picks default colors for the categories.

Can I change the colors of the stacks? I want to specify the colors myself. How would I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/jn2695pc/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "none",
    "legend": {
        "horizontalGap": 10,
        "maxColumns": 1,
        "position": "right",
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "markerSize": 10
    },
    "dataProvider": [{
        "year": 2003,
        "europe": 2.5,
        "namerica": 2.5,
        "asia": 2.1,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.2,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "europe": 2.6,
        "namerica": 2.7,
        "asia": 2.2,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "europe": 2.8,
        "namerica": 2.9,
        "asia": 2.4,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "axisAlpha": 0.3,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Europe",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "europe"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "North America",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "namerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Asia-Pacific",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "asia"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Latin America",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "lamerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Middle-East",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "meast"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Africa",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "africa"
    }],
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    },
    "exportConfig":{
        "menuTop":"20px",
        "menuRight":"20px",
        "menuItems": [{
        "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
        "format": 'png'   
        }]  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in the "fillColors": "#ffffff",
to each of your "graphs": [..]

This will fill it with white:
ie.

```
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Europe",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "fillColors": "#ffffff",
    "valueField": "europe"
},
```